# Node.js program in Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, yaml

I've just started programming in Node.js and in Azure DevOps. I've tried to run a simple Node.js example to see how things work in Azure DevOps, but I've encountered an error and I don't know how to get past it. 
I have this file imported from Github (File1.js):

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/');
});
```

And in my azure-pipelines.yml I have the following code:

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '11.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    command: install

- script: npm compile 'File1.js'
```

I know the last line from the .yml file generates an error, but I don't know how to make the connection to the .js file in order to run it. If I take out that line, everything works fine, but... it doesn't run the file... Please help with any solutions/hints. They will be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you are not supposed to run it on the build agent, just compile it and package and deploy to the target server\paas offering

Comment: @4c74356b41 Can you please help me a little? I'm new to this and don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a node expert, unfortunately, so I dont really understand what you are trying to do, but in general the workflow is as this:

1. commit code
2. build start, runs compile\tests. packages everything into an archive or a package of some sort
3. release starts to push build results to the server that will run the code and serve the clients.

I have a sample pipeline for nodejs.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '8.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- script: |
    zip -r result.zip . -x .git/**\* > /dev/null
  displayName: 'package results'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/result.zip' 
    artifactName: 'drop' 
  displayName: 'upload artifacts'
```

Comment: Do you have to do something special for the versioning?  Azure DevOps keeps telling me there's no version.

Comment: you should raise a new question, mate